# Visual Studio 2015: Build successful but debugging never stops loading

Tags: c++, debugging, visual-studio-2015

I have this C++ project I am trying to debug in Visual Studio (Community) 2015. The build is always successful, but after that debugging never starts. All that shows up is the Windows loading icon, which just never goes away. Any ideas about what might be wrong?

Comment: Do you use Avast antivirus? There have been several recent questions where Avast is causing this or similar problems.

Comment: Yes! What should I do about it? Is there a way to disable it for Visual Studio?

Comment: I don't use Avast but there should be a way to add an exclusion for the "\Visual Studio 2015\Projects" folder in the Avast settings.

Comment: You need to uninstall it.  Plenty of anti-malware products out there, Avast is the worst of them on a programmer's machine.

Answer (score 2):

The problem was that Avast was interfering with my Visual Studio Projects. I used the instructions at https://forum.avast.com/index.php?topic=139935.0 to get it to work.

Basically you need to exclude your VS projects from Avast's scan.

> ... but simply turning off DeepScreen in Avast 2014 is not enough.  I
>   make multiple apps in Visual STudio 2012, and I can tell you that even
>   with Deep Screen off, Avast will still pop right up and destroy the
>   compiling process by saying the .exe is a virus (the crazy "evo-gen
>   [susp]").  The only way I can get Avast to stop doing that is to
>   manually enter-in exclusion directories for every directory where I
>   create apps!  ...or make an exclusion for some high-level folder.

Answer (score 0):

Try resetting your settings by going here

> *Tools* >> *Import and Export* Settings Wizard >> *Reset* all settings

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problems for Visual Studio 2015 Update 1 on Windows 10.

**For me, the only solution, which helped is to install this package:**

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=49029

*"FIX: Devenv.com process freezes after you execute devenv.com /build command in Visual Studio 2015 "* https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3092422