# C++ Executable doesn't run

Tags: c++, visual-studio, console

I have created a C++ Project in Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate.
The IDE succesfully compiles my .cpp File.
Now if start the Debugger (F5 or Ctrl-F5) Visual Studio becomes completely unresponsive (like a freeze) and my mouse cursor changes to indicate something is loading/working.
Usually the console would pop up at this point and show the output of my program, but the console never shows up.
However in the Taskmanager I can see three new processes named after my program ("Test.exe" in my case).

First I thought my IDE is the problem so I reinstalled it. Problem still persisted.
I tried running the .exe and some other C++ .exe-Files manually (without using the IDE) but the result was the same. Console didn't show up and I got three new processes in the Taskmanager.

I really don't know what causes this problem. Any ideas?

Comment: Do you have an antivirus running? There are known problems, especially with Avast.

Comment: Do you run Avast Anti-virus?  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33718236/visual-studio-2015-build-successful-but-debugging-never-stops-loading

Comment: Thanks you are all right.